# What causes this Standard-ML type error?

Tags: functional-programming, type-inference, sml, hindley-milner

I was trying to make a tail-recursive version of this very simple SML function:

```
fun suffixes [] = [[]]
  | suffixes (x::xs) = (x::xs) :: suffixes xs;
```

During the course of this, I was using type annotations on the paramaters. The following code shows this, and causes a type error (given below), whereas if I simply remove the type annotations, SML accepts it with no problem, giving the whole function the same signature as the simpler function above.

```
fun suffixes_tail xs =
    let
        fun suffixes_helper [] acc = []::acc
          | suffixes_helper (x::xs:'a list) (acc:'b list) =
                suffixes_helper xs ((x::xs)::acc)
    in
        suffixes_helper xs []
    end;
```

Error:

```
$ sml typeerror.sml 
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.71 [built: Thu Sep 17 16:48:42 2009]
[opening typeerror.sml]
val suffixes = fn : 'a list -> 'a list list
typeerror.sml:17.81-17.93 Error: operator and operand don't agree [UBOUND match]
  operator domain: 'a list * 'a list list
  operand:         'a list * 'b list
  in expression:
    (x :: xs) :: acc
typeerror.sml:16.13-17.94 Error: types of rules don't agree [UBOUND match]
  earlier rule(s): 'a list * 'Z list list -> 'Z list list
  this rule: 'a list * 'b list -> 'Y
  in rule:
    (x :: xs : 'a list,acc : 'b list) =>
      (suffixes_helper xs) ((x :: xs) :: acc)
/usr/local/smlnj-110.71/bin/sml: Fatal error -- Uncaught exception Error with 0
 raised at ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
```

There are two errors given. The latter seems to be less important here, a mismatch between the two clauses of suffixes_helper. The first is the one I don't understand. I annotate to state that the first param is of type `'a:list` and that the second param is of type `'b:list`. Should not the Hindley-Milner type inference algorithm, which is built of top of general unification as I understand it, be able to unify `'b:list` with `'a:list list`, using a substitution of `'b ---> 'a list`?

EDIT: An answer suggests it may have something to do with the type inference algorithm disallowing inferred types which in some sense are more strict than the ones given by the type annotations. I would guess that such a rule would only apply to annotations on parameters and on a function as a whole. I have no idea if this is correct. In any case, I tried moving the type annotations over to the function body, and I get the same sort of error:

```
fun suffixes_helper [] acc = []::acc
    | suffixes_helper (x::xs) acc =
          suffixes_helper (xs:'a list) (((x::xs)::acc):'b list);
```

The error is now:

```
typeerror.sml:5.67-5.89 Error: expression doesn't match constraint [UBOUND match]
  expression: 'a list list
  constraint: 'b list
  in expression:
    (x :: xs) :: acc: 'b list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about SML, but F#, another functional language, gives a warning in this kind of situation. Giving an error may be a bit harsh, but it makes sense: if the programmer introduces an extra type variable 'b, and if 'b must be of type 'a list, the function might not be as generic as the programmer intended, which is worth reporting.

Comment: Thanks, that was something I had not considered: That when a type annotation is given in the parameters, the type inference may be implemented to disallow an inferred type that is more strict than the given parameters. However, I get the same sort of error if I put the type annotations inside the body of the function. I'll edit my question to show this.

Comment: you're still annotating a type that is less strict than the inferred type

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
fun suffixes_tail xs =
    let
        fun suffixes_helper [] acc = []::acc
          | suffixes_helper (x::xs:'a list) (acc:'a list list) =
                suffixes_helper xs ((x::xs)::acc)
    in
        suffixes_helper xs []
    end
```

As Joh and newacct say, `'b list` is too loose.  When you give the explicit type annotation

```
fun suffixes_helper (_ : 'a list) (_ : 'b list) = ...
```

it is implicitly quantified as

```
fun suffixes_helper (_ : (All 'a).'a list) (_ : (All 'b).'b list) = ...
```

and obviously `'b = 'a list` cannot be true `(All a')` **and** `(All b')` simultaneously.

Without the explicit type annotation, type inference can do the right thing, which is to unify the types.  And really, SML's type system is simple enough that (as far as I am aware) it is never undecidable, so explicit type annotations should never be necessary.  Why do you want to put them in here?

Comment: Thanks, with three answers all essentially laying out the same reason, I accept that this is the explanation. My initial understanding (hence by surprise at SML's behaviour) was that type annotations added type information on an equal footing with any inferred types, so they could be unified both "up" (more general) and "down" (more specific).

Comment: And to answer your question why I would want type annotations in the first place: While it is also my understanding that SML never needs type annotations, they may add readability, and (more appropriate in my case) they may help narrow down compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

When you use type variables like `'a` and `'b`, that means that `'a` and `'b` can be set to *anything*, *independently*. So for example it should work if I decided that `'b` was `int` and `'a` was `float`; but obviously that is not valid in this case because it turns out that `'b` must be `'a list`.